# Pandas Normalize or Standardize grouped by category

Tags: python, pandas

Given the data frame df computed as

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
  'type': ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a'],
  'x1': np.random.rand(30), #np.arange(10),
  'x2': np.random.rand(30)/2
})
df['x3'] = df.x1 > df.x2
df['x1']=df.apply(lambda x: x['x1']*2  if x['type']=='a' else x['x1'], axis=1)
df['x1']=df.apply(lambda x: x['x1']+10 if x['type']=='b' else x['x1'], axis=1)
df['x2']=df.apply(lambda x: x['x2']*x['x2'] if x['type']=='c' else x['x2'], axis=1)

df = df.append(df).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.append(df).reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

How to do a Normalization / Standardization of Numeric Columns ie 'X1' & 'X2' , grouped by a Category Column 'type' ? In other words, the 'type' =='b' must not interfere in the  Normalization for data which 'type' !='b'.

**Output**
*df  has the same Colunms but X1 and X2 is transformed to the Standarised or normalized X1 and X2.*

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the numeric columns, then use `groupby().apply()`:

```
# select the number columns
num_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns

def normalize(x):
    return (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())

normalized = df.groupby('type')[num_cols].apply(normalize)

# check
normalized.agg(['min','max'])
```

Output:

```
      x1   x2
min  0.0  0.0
max  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Sorry for the ambiquity, I have updated the question. Output df  has the same Colunms but X1 and X2 is transformed to the Standarised or normalized X1 and X2. Thanks for your effort. Could you please make it appropriate to the expected output

Comment: @VZG just assign back: `df[num_cols] = df.groupby(....)...` instead of asigning it as `normalized`.